# Get Master Page Control Value In Content Page static webmethod in c#

Tags: c#, master-pages, webmethod

I can fetch `MasterPage` control value in `Content Page`

but I can't understand how to fetch `MasterPage` control value in `Content Page` in `static webmethod`

on google, I found many interesting articles but all of them use `ajax` and `jquery` technology

but `ajax` and `jquery` is not suitable for me in this case

any suggestions, please?

my code below

**masterpage**

```
public partial class MasterPage : MasterPage
{
    public string UserNamePropertyOnMasterPage
    {
        get
        {
             // Get value of control on master page
             return lblUserName.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            // Set new value for control on master page 
            lblUserName.Text = value;
        }
    }
}

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <span style="font-size: 25px; background-color: greenyellow">
                <asp:Label ID="lblUserName" runat="server" Text="Shazam"></asp:Label>
            </span>
    </form>
```

**code-behind of Default.aspx.cs**

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            lblCurrentUserName.Font.Size = 20;
            lblCurrentUserName.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            lblCurrentUserName.Text = "Value Received in Content Page : " + Master.UserNamePropertyOnMasterPage;
        }
    }

    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public static void SetLabel(string UserNamePropertyOnMasterPage)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

        Label Hname = (Label)Master.UserNamePropertyOnMasterPage;
        lblCurrentUserName.Text = Hname;
    }
}
```

**markup of Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="MasterPage.master" 
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="MasterPage.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <asp:Label ID="lblCurrentUserName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to call a master page method from a static web method.  This is a fundamental concept to understand in C#.  Basically the master page does not exist during the web request.  Only the web method is called.

Use JavaScript/jQuery to update the current page HTML.